# IB Expert Access - IBExpert.stg storage

Tags: database, storage, ibexpert

### I have a Firebird 2.5 Database in IB Expert; whenever I open IBExpert I get this following error:

IBExpert currently uses IBExpert.stg (C:Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\HK-Software\IBExpert\IBExpert.stg) as a main storage for its data.

This way is obsolete now and will not be supported in the future.

Instead we strongly recommend to setup IBExpert  User Database in Options|Environment Options| User Database.

---

What is the solution for this? What should I do to eliminate this message/error ? I am completely new to Firebird/IBExpert, so any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`IBExpert.stg` is  the database where IBExpert keep the own data by default(in own format). You can set own  firebird database instead.

To do this use : 
`Options => Environment Options  => IbExpert User Database`

- check `Allow user database` check box;
- write database name in `User database connection string` edit box;
- press `Create and Init User database` button.

**Update**

Just now I find this:

http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.EnvironmentOptions?from=Doc.2017#IBEUserDB